# Running Different Stored Procedures in Parallel in EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, asynchronous, entity-framework-6

I have many different stored procedures that I want to fire off in Parallel to improve the performance of my MVC web application. These stored procedures gather information from multiple sources and return different data types. For the sake of simplicity, let's say I only had two, returning different complex data types:

- ups_Proc1 returns a List of usp_Proc1
- usp_Proc2 returns a List of usp_Proc2

and so on....

I could do one of these numbers, but it would fire them off in a series:

```
List<usp_Task1> taskOneResult = await db.usp_Task1(parms).AsQueryable()
                                                         .ToListAsync();
List<usp_Task2> taskTwoResult = await db.usp_Task2(parms).AsQueryable()
                                                         .ToListAsync();
```

The solutions I've seen use `await Task.WhenAll()` and you pass in an array of tasks, but mine are tasks with different return types. So how does one fire multiple stored procedures in parallel when dealing with different complex return types?

UPDATE- 5/20/2015

Finally got a working solution that I believe is handling all the tasks in parallel. I had to use `Task.Factory.StartNew()` command to create each function as a task to be passed into `Task.WaitAll()`.

I rapped all this into a new class that contained a `List<>` for each stored procedure return type I'm working with, allowing me to handle all my business logic there. The code in the constructor looked a little like this:

```
var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CallStoredProc1(parms));
var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CallStoredProc2(parms));

var taskList = new List<Task> { task1, task2 };

Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
```

`CallStoredProc1()` and `CallStoredProc2()` are private void methods where I do my stored procedure calls and handle data conversion.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How many return types are we talking here? Why not use a struct or class and define your properties, and then have the tasks set each property of the holder class, and then just do a `WaitAll()` for all of the tasks?

Comment: Either use separate dbContexts with multiple threads, or using the .Future() extension and a single thread. The first will be parallel, the second will be sequential, but without the multiple network ping-pongs.

Comment: In this instance I will be using 3 stored procedures and they touch various data sources to build information for my page. I have made classes that define the properties of these 3 return types and convert them from the complex return type of the stored procedure to the classes I will be using to construct my partial views... My application is still on the smaller side, so I'm looking for an approach that is scale-able..

Comment: You could define a (possibly abstract) base class for all of the result types, then descend each specific result type from that.  Then your `Task.WhenAll` would just need to work with common properties.

Answer (score 2):

Figured I would repost my update as a solution.

Finally got a working solution that I believe is handling all the tasks in parallel. I had to use `Task.Factory.StartNew()` command to create each function as a task to be passed into `Task.WaitAll()`.

I rapped all this into a new class that contained a `List<>` for each stored procedure return type I'm working with, allowing me to handle all my business logic there. The code in the constructor looked a little like this:

```
var task1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CallStoredProc1(parms));
var task2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CallStoredProc2(parms));

var taskList = new List<Task> { task1, task2 };

Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());
```

`CallStoredProc1()` and `CallStoredProc2()` are private void methods where I do my stored procedure calls and handle data conversion.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated!

Comment: how do you work with result set of the stored procedure then ? For example when stored procedure return datatable.

Answer (score 0):

`Task.WhenAll` is supported for `Task` inputs which you have. So use `Task.WhenAll` first to make sure all tasks are completed. Then, use `Task.Result` to get the actual results from all tasks.